# project reference added but namespace is not recognized only for specefic project(vs2019)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

[The references in BankManagementSystem.Repository. apparently they are working for every other references except the reference of BankManagementSystem.Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBsw9.png)

[here, the reference is added but only the namespace of BankManagementSystem.Entity is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuQkD.png)

Comment: It is really difficult to answer simply based on 2 screenshots, but what is project type of "BankManagementSystem.Entity"?? 
Is it same as other projects??

Comment: they all are class libraries except BankManagementSystem.App.

Comment: Is the target framework of your BankManagementSystem.Entity the same as other class libraries?

Comment: Hope "BankManagementSystem.Entity" is having a pubic interface, which can be used in other projects. Is it possible for you to upload code and share its link?